# Android KeyboardView not sizing correctly

Tags: android

I've recently had a problem with Android Keyboard views.

What I wanted to achieve was a decent keyboard, where I could add key spacing in pixels and the rest of the space would be shared by the keys depending on how I weighted them.

I also found percentage widths were inaccurate (rows ends varied by +-6px).

Comment: I'm trying to put a keyboard in a square view on the right side of screen in landscape mode. But after some layout change, it messes up the key sizes, making them huge in width. That is because it assumes that will fit the whole screen in horizontal. I tried to force invalidate(), invalidateAllKeys() and requestLayout() and no success. Do you have any ideas?

Comment: It's been ages since I've done this lol... So the first layout of the keyboard is fine, but subsequent ones aren't? What changes between the first and second layouts that causes the second one to fail?

Comment: Ohhh, now i remember that i (kinda) solved exactly this problem (the 6px) about year ago with percentage sizes like 25%p, 50%p but that leads to other problems (those above). I'm experimenting now with your solution. My case is simpler - i need a square numpad with some buttons with double size. It feels nice to see someone having the same awful problem as you. lol :) I'll write again to tell the results.

Comment: 2 more questions - when do you call fixKeyboard() exactly? and do you know a way to change the keys default appearance?

Comment: Right then! I use fix keyboard like so: `Keyboard k = new Keyboard(this, RESID);
fixKeyboard(k, 12); 
keyboardView.setKeyboard(k);`

As for the default appearance of the keys: No, I'm not sure how to fix this, I never tried. If you want to do a good job (and I intend to do this when I get some time), you should really just roll your own KeyboardView. It shouldn't be that hard, and you can make it as fancy and as awesome as you like!

Comment: Looks like I stabilized it now without a fix function. I use 3 different similar numpads and switching between them for now doesn't cause problems when I've set rigid sizes. The way to customize the drawable is the attribute 'keyBackground'. The other used attributes can be seen in the constructor of KeyboardView http://tinyurl.com/oh8deww. The other way - complete redefining onDraw() like http://stackoverflow.com/a/21104699/458668

Comment: Great! Well I'm glad you got it working!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Each key is given a width, usually 64 pixels. For a half-normal width key I would assign 32px. For double I gave it 128px. Etc.

The keyboard is then run through a function called "fixKeyboard" which decides upon the width for each key. You tell it how many 64px width keys per row, and it will scale the keys to a size that works. (i.e keysPerStandardRow == how many pixels wide the keyboard is / 64px)

```
private void fixKeyboard(Keyboard k, int keysPerStandardRow)
{
    List<Key> keys = k.getKeys();
    int dw = GlobalHelperFunctions.getDisplay(this).getWidth();
    int ttly = 0;
    int divisor = 64 * keysPerStandardRow;
    int ttl_weights = 0;
    for (Key key : keys)
    {
        //See below for the deal with 424242
        int weight = key.width + (key.gap == 424242 ? 0 : key.gap);
        if (key.gap == 424242)
            key.gap = 0;
        else
            key.gap = (ttl_weights + key.gap) * dw / divisor - ttl_weights * dw / divisor;
        key.width = (ttl_weights + key.width) * dw / divisor - ttl_weights * dw / divisor;
        if (key.y != ttly)
        {
            ttl_weights = 0;
            ttly = key.y;
        }
        key.x = ttl_weights * dw / divisor;
        ttl_weights += weight;
    }
}

...

static public Display GlobalHelperFunctions.getDisplay(Context c)
{
    if (c != null)
    {
        WindowManager wm = (WindowManager)c.getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE);
        if (wm != null)
        {
            return wm.getDefaultDisplay();
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

Alas, this was not the end of the story. It seems that the keyboard view/keyboard decides upon the width of the keyboard the moment you hand it the XML file. If for some reason you've changed the keys like I have, android scales them back into its pre-calculated box. I didn't want this, obviously. So here's what I did: I simply forced it to have the maximum possible width by defining a huge horizontal gap in between each key (424242px), which I then reset to 0 when running fixKeyboard.

Since I was using this approach, you can define gaps easily by simply not using the trigger number! Here's my QWERTY keyboard you can use if you'd like as an example:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <Keyboard xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
         android:keyHeight="80px"
         android:horizontalGap="424242px"
         android:verticalGap="2px" >
     <Row android:keyWidth="64px">
         <Key android:keyLabel="1" android:keycode="KEYCODE_1"/>
         <Key android:keyLabel="2" android:keycode="KEYCODE_2"/>
         <Key android:keyLabel="3" android:keycode="KEYCODE_3"/>
         <Key android:keyLabel="4" android:keycode="KEYCODE_4"/>

         <Key android:keyLabel="5" android:keycode="KEYCODE_5"/>
         <Key android:keyLabel="6" android:keycode="KEYCODE_6"/>
         <Key android:keyLabel="7" android:keycode="KEYCODE_7"/>
         <Key android:keyLabel="8" android:keycode="KEYCODE_8"/>

         <Key android:keyLabel="9" android:keycode="KEYCODE_9" />
         <Key android:keyLabel="0" android:keycode="KEYCODE_0"/>
         <Key android:keyIcon="@android:drawable/ic_input_delete" android:keyOutputText="◁" android:keyWidth="128px" android:codes="0x25C1" android:isRepeatable="true"/>
     </Row>
     <Row android:keyWidth="64px">
         <Key android:keyLabel="q" android:keycode="KEYCODE_Q" />
         <Key android:keyLabel="w" android:keycode="KEYCODE_W"/>
         <Key android:keyLabel="e" android:keycode="KEYCODE_E" />
         <Key android:keyLabel="r" android:keycode="KEYCODE_R" />

         <Key android:keyLabel="t" android:keycode="KEYCODE_T"/>
         <Key android:keyLabel="y" android:keycode="KEYCODE_Y"  />
         <Key android:keyLabel="u" android:keycode="KEYCODE_U"/>
         <Key android:keyLabel="i" android:keycode="KEYCODE_I" />

         <Key android:keyLabel="o" android:keycode="KEYCODE_O" />
         <Key android:keyLabel="p" android:keycode="KEYCODE_P" />
         <Key android:keyLabel="・"/>
         <Key android:keyIcon="@android:drawable/ic_menu_preferences" android:keyOutputText="●" android:codes="0x25CF"/>
     </Row>
     <Row android:keyWidth="64px">
         <Key android:keyLabel="　" android:keyHeight="0px" android:keyWidth="0px" android:horizontalGap="32px"/>
         <Key android:keyLabel="a" android:keycode="KEYCODE_A"/>
         <Key android:keyLabel="s" android:keycode="KEYCODE_S"/>
         <Key android:keyLabel="d" android:keycode="KEYCODE_D"/>

         <Key android:keyLabel="f" android:keycode="KEYCODE_F" />
         <Key android:keyLabel="g" android:keycode="KEYCODE_G"/>
         <Key android:keyLabel="h" android:keycode="KEYCODE_H"/>
         <Key android:keyLabel="j" android:keycode="KEYCODE_J" />

         <Key android:keyLabel="k" android:keycode="KEYCODE_K" />
         <Key android:keyLabel="l" android:keycode="KEYCODE_L" />
         <Key android:keyLabel="ENTER" android:keyOutputText="◒" android:keyWidth="96px"/>
         <Key android:keyLabel="カタ"  android:keyOutputText="◎" android:codes="0x25CE"/>
     </Row>
     <Row android:keyWidth="64px">
         <Key android:keyLabel="「" />
         <Key android:keyLabel="z" android:keycode="KEYCODE_Z"/>
         <Key android:keyLabel="x" android:keycode="KEYCODE_X"/>
         <Key android:keyLabel="c" android:keycode="KEYCODE_C"/>

         <Key android:keyLabel="v" android:keycode="KEYCODE_V" />
         <Key android:keyLabel="b" android:keycode="KEYCODE_B"/>
         <Key android:keyLabel="n" android:keycode="KEYCODE_N"/>
         <Key android:keyLabel="m" android:keycode="KEYCODE_M"/>

         <Key android:keyLabel="、"/>
         <Key android:keyLabel="。"/>
         <Key android:keyLabel="⇧" android:keycode="KEYCODE_SHIFT_RIGHT" android:isModifier="true"/>
         <Key android:keyLabel="HW" android:keyOutputText="◍" android:codes="0x25CD"/>
     </Row>
     <Row android:keyWidth="64px">
         <Key android:keyLabel=" " android:keyWidth="704px"/>
         <Key android:keyLabel="ひら"  android:keyOutputText="◐" android:codes="0x25D0"/>
     </Row>
 </Keyboard>
```

A few important things: to make a gap BEFORE a key, I just added a 0 width key. `<Key android:keyLabel="　" android:keyHeight="0px" android:keyWidth="0px" android:horizontalGap="32px"/>`

Another thing: For the control keys (Like the one that opens the IME menu, I've used special characters to alert the code: `android:keyOutputText="◐"` etc.

It took me a while to search for the way to open the IME menu, so here's how:
[How to set/call an new input method in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9777406/how-to-set-call-an-new-input-method-in-android)

HTH, all code is public domain